# php include number in string

Tags: php, html

I have a simple PHP foreach loop to populate a 'select' code with options.  The result is not as expected.

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($geo_area as $area) {
   echo '<option value=' . $i++ . '>' . $area . '</option>';
}
```

The result is:

```
<option value="0">World</option>
<option value="0">Europe</option>
<option value="0">Scandinavia</option>
<option value="0">East Europe</option>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try brackets: `($i++)`

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://3v4l.org/fmf5R

Comment: Likewise, the code works correctly for me.

Comment: `foreach ($geo_area as $key=>$area) {echo "<option value='$key'>$value</option>";}`

Answer (score 1):

copy this and past:

```
echo "<select name='something'>";
$i = 1;
foreach ($geo_area as $key=> $area) {
   echo "<option value='$i'>" . $area. "</option>";
   $i++;
}
echo  "</select>";
```

the output is a select tag whit options.

Comment: That's how it appears in Chrome Dev Tools->Sources but in Dev Tools->Elements is shows 'value="0"'.  A query of the value always shows "0".

Comment: @JohnEmerson you want to have a select tag that has options with these values?

Comment: I edited my code, take a look, and say to me what happened.

Comment: Used brackets as suggested by @Michael but gave identical results with value="0" in Dev Tools->Elements and the correct numbering under Dev Tools->Sources.  Still issues incorrect value of "0"..

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo "<select name='select'>";

$geo_area= array('one','two','three'); // this is your array of information
$i = 1;
foreach ($geo_area as $key=> $area) {
   echo "<option value='$i'>" . $area. "</option>";
   $i++;
}
echo  "</select>";
```

Comment: Now solved - original code was working but was being overwritten in a later part of the code. All help appreciated.